# I want to first connect to aws and hit a python command from Nodejs via Api. Not sure how to do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I want to execute 'python3 sample.py --path.data=/root/tej4' command from nodejs.The below is my code -

```
const runningPython = async(req,res,next) => {
    ssh.connect({
        host: '******',
        port: 22,
        username: 'ubuntu',
        privateKey: '*******'
    }).then(function () {
     exec('python3 sample.py --path.data=/root/tej4', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        }
      
        // the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
      });
    })
    }
```

But what I am getting response is its trying to run locally rather than on aws cli. Not sure how to achieve this?

```
Error: Command failed: python3 sample.py --path.data=/root/tej4
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:397:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5) {
  killed: false,
  code: 9009,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'python3 sample.py --path.data=/root/tej4'
}
stdout: 
stderr: Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
```

Comment: Unrelated to AWS in general. What library are you using to connect, should it really be `exec`, not maybe `ssh.exec`, is python installed on the target machine, ...?

Comment: Yes python is installed on aws

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ssh lib, but for sudo su and running multiple commands switch to ssh2shell, the code for that is mentioned below:

```
const runningPython = async (req, res, next) => {
  var host = {
    server: {
      host: ***** ,
      username: ***** ,
      privateKey: fs.readFileSync('ppk file path'),
    },
    commands: ["sudo su -", "python3 sample.py --path.data=root/tej4"],
    onCommandComplete: function (command, response, sshObj) {
      if (sshObj.debug) {
        this.emit("msg", this.sshObj.server.host + ": host.onCommandComplete event, command: " + command);
      }
      if (command === "sudo su -" && response.indexOf("/root") != -1) {

        sshObj.commands.unshift("msg:The command and response check worked. Added another cd command.");
        sshObj.commands.unshift("cd .ssh");
      } else if (command === "python3 sample.py --path.data=root/tej4") {
        this.emit("msg", response);

      }
    },

    onEnd: function (sessionText, sshObj) {

      if (sshObj.debug) {
        this.emit("msg", this.sshObj.server.host + ": host.onEnd event");
      }
    }
  };

  let SSH = new SSH2Shell(host),
    //Use a callback function to process the full session text
    callback = function (sessionText) {
      console.log(sessionText)
    }

  //Start the process
  SSH.connect(callback);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an instance of type `node_ssh` and use that instance to call `connect` and `executeCommand` methods

```js
const node_ssh = require('node-ssh');
const ssh = new node_ssh();

ssh
  .connect({
        host: '******',
        port: 22,
        username: 'ubuntu',
        privateKey: '*******'
  })
  .then(() => {
    ssh.execCommand('python3 sample.py --path.data=/root/tej4', { cwd:'/your-python-script-path-here' })
       .then((result) => {
          console.log('STDOUT: ' + result.stdout)
          console.log('STDERR: ' + result.stderr)
       });
```

Comment: Hi, I tried exactly same but its throwing this error - AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: options must be a valid object
    at NodeSSH.execCommand (C:\Users\nikeeta_kurrey\Log-monitoring\node_modules\node-ssh\lib\cjs\index.js:271:25)
    at C:\Users\nikeeta_kurrey\Log-monitoring\Controller\logs_api.js:364:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  generatedMessage: false,
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: false,
  expected: true,
  operator: '=='

Comment: @Nikeetakurrey, can you try this

Comment: Hi @Allan Chua , this will work but the only problem is it should first run sudo su - followed by python3 sample.py --path.data=/root/tej4 this command. I tried passing an array of commands and looping inside .then but not working.

Comment: If you run it with sudo, the python alias is not available there because python was installed by another user. If you'd like to use sudo, I propose to install python using the root user instead.